# Getting values from text box in controller and save it in another model

Tags: cakephp, controller, view

I have a controller called users_controller and one action called getdata().getdata.ctp is the view corresponding to that action. in that view i added a elemet called route.ctp which contains a from data.my problem is i want to retrive all the vaues from form element in the getdata() method and save it in another model Route.How we can do this?
for this i write the form action  in the element route.ctp

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => 'getdata'))); ?>
```

And in the users_controllers getdata() action , i write

```
    function getdata()
          {
     $this->commuter(); // it call a function commuter() in this same controller for displaying some data in the view.
   $this->layout='custm';
   $this->loadModel('Defineroute');
   if (!empty($this->data) )
   {
       $this->Defineroute->create(); //Defineroute is a model. in this model i want save the form date. for that i created one table "defineroutes"


       $this->Defineroute->save($this->data);

   }
     }
```

Comment: is your data posing in your controller action

Comment: @liyakat i didnt get data in controler..also it is not saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few observations:

#### Observation 1

The model that the form associates the data with is `User` and not `Defineroute`. If the fields are the same for both models, you would have to de-reference the `User` model in the `$this->data` property.

So instead of doing:

```
$this->Defineroute->save($this->data);
```

Do:

```
$this->Defineroute->save($this->data['User']);
```

*Update*

If you debug your post data by doing a `pr($this->data)`, you should see the following:

```
array('User' => array(/*Your User fields*/))
```

That's why if you do `$this->data['User']` you will get just the fields for your `Defineroute` model.

#### Observation 2

You don't really need to be calling `$this->Defineroute->create();` because you're only creating one record per request so there is really no need to reset the active record in the model.

#### Observation 3

Calls to another controller function like `$this->commuter();` are fine as long as they are  utility functions and not actions. The reason for this is that you create dependencies between your controller actions, and if you change one in the future, you may break the other. If the function sets view variables from one model, consider shifting the code into the model itself.

Comment: observation 1 -i want to save the data into defineroute table. i created one model Defineroute for that.                                               Observation2-each time i want to add data to the defineroute table, then the need of   $this->Defineroute->create(); is necessary???

Comment: Observation 1: That's fine, but your form keys your fields using the `User` model which your `Defineroute` table doesn't know about; that's why I said de-reference it. Observation 2: You're not doing it in a loop, so it is not. I'm guessing your adding one `Defineroute` per submission of form (post-back to server). The active record of a model is not persisted between requests, so you needn't worry.

Comment: then how to add fields data directly to defineroute

Comment: That's fine, but your form keys your fields using the User model which your Defineroute table doesn't know about--this is the problem how to solve it.the define route and user table are differnt.only two fields arre same

Comment: @SibinF, it might be useful to other people if you update your question to include some code that describes what you want `$this->data` to contain? From my perspective, I can't really see much which is wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: Observation 2 is wrong! you ALWAYS need to call create() prior to an insert (only for updates you dont do that).

Comment: @mark I don't disagree with you. However, If you can rely on the fact the model state not being modified then `create()` doesn't really achieve anything. The [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array) examples could be clearer in this area as the language used suggests it's optional.

Comment: The documentation is quite clear - do you see that big blue box containing "If you want to insert a new row instead of updating an existing one you should always call create() first. This avoids conflicts with possible prior save calls in callbacks or other places." *Should* merely means: it might work without it, but it is doomed to break at some point in the future. So why not doing it right the first time?